# How to add more data while serializing to xml

Tags: xml, .net-2.0

I have an xml

```
  <child>
  <parameter>
    <displayName >animal</displayName>
    <type>terrestrial</type>
  </parameter>
  <subchild >
    <parameter>
      <displayName >horse</displayName>
      <type>terrestrial</type>
    </parameter>
  </subchild>
</child>
```

and it is represented as class

public partial class child {

```
private childSubchild[] itemsField;


[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("subchild", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public childSubchild[] Items {
    get {
        return this.itemsField;
    }
    set {
        this.itemsField = value;
    }
}
```

}

public partial class childSubchild {

```
private childSubchildParameter[] parameterField;

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("parameter", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public childSubchildParameter[] parameter {
    get {
        return this.parameterField;
    }
    set {
        this.parameterField = value;
    }
}
```

}

public partial class childSubchildParameter {

```
private string displayNameField;

private string typeField;

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public string displayName {
    get {
        return this.displayNameField;
    }
    set {
        this.displayNameField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public string type {
    get {
        return this.typeField;
    }
    set {
        this.typeField = value;
    }
}
```

}

i need to add more subchild while serializing data

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Child));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
            Child child = (Child)xs.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }


    [XmlRoot("child")]
    public class Child
    {
        [XmlElement("parameter")]
        public ChildSubchildParameter[] parameter {get; set; }
        [XmlElement("subchild")]
        public SubChild[] subchild {get; set;}
    }
    [XmlRoot("subchild")]
    public class SubChild
    {
        [XmlElement("parameter")]
        public ChildSubchildParameter[] parameter {get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("parameter")]
    public class ChildSubchildParameter
    {
        [XmlElement("displayName")]
        public string displayName {get; set; }
        [XmlElement("type")]
        public string type {get; set; }
    }
}
​
```